# Enabling PREEMPT_RT affecting system drivers

Tags: kernel

We are presently using the RTC PCF85263A with an iMX6ULL processor, running Linux 5.15.52 on Yocto 4.0. Additionally,

I have added this RT-Patch to my Linux kernel even though it is not the same version as my Linux kernel:

https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.15/older/patch-5.15.55-rt48.patch.gz

Additionally, I have enabled the CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT in the kernel. Before enabling this, every interface was working perfectly. However, after enabling it, I am facing issue in CAN Communication.Is this is normal or Is there anything I need to change or am I missing out on something? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.